# What are the performance implications when loading collections in different ways?

Tags: collection, performance, optimization

Given two ways to loading a category collection:

```
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
$children->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $parent_id)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', 1)
    ->addAttributeToSort('position');
```

Or

```
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $parent_id)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', 1)
    ->addAttributeToSort('position');
```

Are there any differences in performance between them?

Comment: I'd've thought that any execution timing improvement would be minute by using the second example.

Comment: i guess second one take less time

Answer (score 1):

There is no significant difference between the 2 of them.
Through the chaining mechanism, each method is applied to the result of the previous method.
So both codes do the same thing and they are both similar to:

```
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
$children->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$children->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $parent_id);
$children->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);
$children->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', 1);
$children->addAttributeToSort('position');
```

This happens because the methods `addAttributeToSelect` `addAttributeToFilter` and `addAttributeToSort` return `$this`...the instance of the current object.
Internally "stuff" may happen differently in all the cases, but I have no idea how the PHP interpreter works.

The result is the same and the time it takes should not have a significant difference.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there shouldn't be any difference what so ever but if you want to benchmark you can use Magento's build in Varien Profiler, read more about that [here](http://santoshyadavcse.wordpress.com/2013/01/01/magento-varien-profiler/).

```
Varien_Profiler::start(‘collection-method-one’); //start the profiler 

$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
$children->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $parent_id)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', 1)
    ->addAttributeToSort('position');

Varien_Profiler::stop(‘your-key’);// end the profiler

Varien_Profiler::start(‘collection-method-two’); //start the profiler 

$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $parent_id)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', 1)
    ->addAttributeToSort('position');

Varien_Profiler::stop(‘your-two’);// end the profiler
```

Now turn on the profiler in the backend under `System > Configuration > Developer` and see what comes out...

Comment: Yeah...profiler. totally forgot about that.